# Cannot import @material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, yarnpkg

I am working on a React project, using Material UI React components. I want to import `MuiThemeProvider` in `src/index.js` like so 
`import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";`
.

But I get

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

Checking the `/node_modules/@material-ui/styles` there is no `MuiThemeProvider`. I dont understand that. Installing the project freshly on another computer, the `/node_modules/@material-ui/styles` contains a `MuiThemeProvider`.  I removed the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled with `yarn install`, but that did not do anything. 
When I install the project freshly on another computer, it works fine.

These are the dependencies from `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "epsg-index": "^0.27.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "immutable-prop-types": "^0.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "phoenix": "^1.4.8",
    "proj4": "^2.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rc-tooltip": "^3.7.3",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "jsdom": "^13.2.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/**/fsevents": "^1.2.9"
  },
```

Why would it install differently on two machines?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is **not** necessary to explicitly pull in `@material-ui/styles` (as indicated in Davin's answer). In fact, including that package explicitly in your `package.json` [can lead to problems](https://material-ui.com/blog/september-2019-update/) due to it getting pulled into your bundle more than once.

From https://material-ui.com/blog/september-2019-update/:

> Starting with v4.5.1, the documentation mentions @material-ui/core/styles as much as possible.
>
> This change removes the need to install the @material-ui/styles package directly. It prevents the duplication of @material-ui/styles in bundles and avoids confusion.

Also see https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-core-styles-vs-material-ui-styles

The problem with your import is that you had:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
```

instead of:

```
import {MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

The first would only work if `MuiThemeProvider` was a separate file or directory within `@material-ui/core/styles`, but it is not. The second syntax is for a named export from `@material-ui/core/styles` which is [what it is](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/styles/index.js#L16).

Comment: Ah, so basically `<MuiThemeProvider />` is just an alias of `< ThemeProvider />`, was scratching my head when I see this available, but the material-UI examples only mention `<ThemeProvider />` so was confused. Guess it'll help people that want it to be more specific.

Comment: @ShaungCheng `MuiThemeProvider` was the only name for it in v3. The alias was retained in v4 for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though you need to pull in another package: `@material-ui/styles`. Then, you can use `ThemeProvider` component to set up themes [as described here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/).

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    ...
})

...
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyChild />
    </ThemeProvider>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the new library: `@mui/material/` Yeah, v5 has been released!
check: [Migration from v4 to v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/)

As an example this is my app

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#1476A3',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#292977',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
  },
  components: {
    MuiPaper: {
      styleOverrides: {
        rounded: {
          borderRadius: '12px',
        },
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          borderRadius: '8px',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <main>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  </main>
)

export default App
```