# Style problems with higher order component & Material-UI's makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to avoid the invalid hook call error per [How to style components using makeStyles and still have lifecycle methods in Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432167/how-to-style-components-using-makestyles-and-still-have-lifecycle-methods-in-mat).

Not able to tell what I may be doing wrong here. The classnames seem to be generated fine but the styles are not. See the defintion inspector returns for .RecipeReviewCard-avatar-10 below the class code. Full runnable example found [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vz0g2). It seems makeStyles isn't executing, but if I do `withStyles(styles())(RecipeReviewCard)` I get the same hook error.

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  ...snipped for brevity...
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500]
  }
}));

class RecipeReviewCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
      anchorEl: null,
      open: false
    };

    this.handleExpandClick = this.handleExpandClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClickAway = this.handleClickAway.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    ... snipped for brevity...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(RecipeReviewCard);
```

```
.RecipeReviewCard-avatar-10 {
    0: m;
    1: a;
    2: k;
    3: e;
    4: S;
    5: t;
    6: y;
    7: l;
    8: e;
    9: s;
    10: -;
    11: a;
    12: v;
    13: a;
    14: t;
    15: a;
    16: r;
    17: -;
    18: 5;
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple main issues in your sandbox:

- You shouldn't be mixing `makeStyles` with `withStyles`. `makeStyles` should only be used to create a custom hook to be called in a function component. Just remove the `makeStyles` call.
- You should import `withStyles` from `@material-ui/core/styles` rather than from `@material-ui/styles` otherwise it won't have access to the default theme.

Here is a working (at least the styles) version of your sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import ShareIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Share";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";

import { Input, Checkbox } from "@progress/kendo-react-inputs";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest
    })
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)"
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500]
  }
});

class RecipeReviewCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
      anchorEl: null,
      open: false
    };

    this.handleExpandClick = this.handleExpandClick.bind(this);
    this.handleClickAway = this.handleClickAway.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    console.log(classes);
    const isNew = this.props.isNew || false;
    const iconClass = clsx(classes.expand, {
      [classes.expandOpen]: this.state.expanded
    });
    return (
      <div className="ccard">
        <Popper
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          placement="bottom-end"
          transition
        >
          {({ TransitionProps }) => (
            <Paper>
              <Typography className={classes.typography}>
                Delete?
                <br />
                Other?
              </Typography>
            </Paper>
          )}
        </Popper>
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardHeader
            avatar={
              <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
                R
              </Avatar>
            }
            action={
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={this.handleClickAway}>
                <IconButton aria-label="settings" onClick={this.onClick}>
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            }
            title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
            subheader="September 14, 2016"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <div className="">
              <Input
                name="ID"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                label="ID*"
                pattern={"[A-Za-z]+"}
                minLength={2}
                required={true}
                readOnly={!isNew}
                disabled={!isNew}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.id}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <Input
                name="Description"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                label="Description"
                pattern={"[A-Za-z]+"}
                minLength={2}
                onChange={e => this.onChange(e, "description")}
                value={this.state.description}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <Checkbox
                id={"chb1"}
                label="Active"
                name="active"
                labelPlacement="before"
                onChange={e => this.onChange(e, "active")}
                value={this.state.active}
              />
            </div>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              className={iconClass}
              onClick={this.handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={this.state.expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={this.state.expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
                Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron
                and set aside for 10 minutes.
              </Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
                Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep
                skillet over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo,
                and cook, stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8
                minutes. Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving
                chicken and chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves,
                garlic, tomatoes, onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring
                often until thickened and fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add
                saffron broth and remaining 4 1/2 cups chicken broth; bring to a
                boil.
              </Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
                Add rice and stir very gently to distribute. Top with artichokes
                and peppers, and cook without stirring, until most of the liquid
                is absorbed, 15 to 18 minutes. Reduce heat to medium-low, add
                reserved shrimp and mussels, tucking them down into the rice,
                and cook again without stirring, until mussels have opened and
                rice is just tender, 5 to 7 minutes more. (Discard any mussels
                that don’t open.)
              </Typography>
              <Typography>
                Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then
                serve.
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleExpandClick() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }

  onClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  handleClickAway() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  }

  onChange() {}
}

export default withStyles(styles)(RecipeReviewCard);
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Related answers:

- [How to use theme in styles for custom class components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966496/how-to-use-theme-in-styles-for-custom-class-components/57967202#57967202)
- [What is the benefit of using withStyles over makeStyles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697664/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-withstyles-over-makestyles/57702612#57702612)
- [Material-UI withStyles doesn't apply any kind of styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986393/material-ui-withstyles-doesnt-apply-any-kind-of-styles/56994115#56994115)
- [Cannot import @material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432694/cannot-import-material-ui-core-styles-muithemeprovider/58435846#58435846)